# Node.js architecture and app structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've been building a simple Node/Express based chat client with socket.io and am somewhat confused between the import way of adding dependencies vs using closures to pass in dependencies to components.

Here is how the app is structured:

- index.js
- server/server.js (creates express instance)
- server/controllers/ (Contains controllers which require socketIO client)
- server/store.js (creates redis instance)
- server/websocket.js (creates socket.io instance/returns a custom API)

Creating a socketIO client requires an instance of express.Server. 
However, I still need the socketIO client API in the controllers for the express server (To emit/broadcast updates).
Therefore, the socket client is exported by index.js as a promise which, on resolving, is used to setup the controllers for express.

Question:
What would be a good way to hook up components where

- Component A requires an instance of Component B.
- Methods inside component B will require an instance of Component A.
  (Here SocketIO requires an instance of Express, but I also need that SocketIO client in the controllers being used by Express)

The actual code: 
https://github.com/vsr4493/chatbox

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about code review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Node.js ecosystem there is no preferred way of structuring project components, especially for different business cases.

I've implemented a similar web application that needs `socket.io` instance in express controllers and had the same question: 'How should I access `socket` object in controllers?'.

What I did was replacing my express controllers with socket events. So, your codebase can turn into these:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('join', function(user) {
        userStore.join(user)
        emitOnlineCount()
    })

    function emitOnlineCount() {
        io.sockets.emit("onlines", userStore.getUsers().length)
    }

})
```

It's in your hand to keep your code clean and simple.